# extending truncated Barsotti-Tate group  

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve defined over a finite field of char $p$, let $G[1]$ be a truncated Barsotti-Tate grop of level-1. My question is :  can $G[1]$  be extended to a truncated  Barsotti-Tate group of level-2 (or extended to a Barsotti-Tate) over $X$, if not, what is the obstruction (or obstruction space)? Thank you!

Comment: Yes; see Illusie's paper that surveys Grothendieck's work on the deformation theory of p-divisible groups.  Early in there he gives Dieudonne-module arguments of Gabber and Ekedahl to handle the extension problem over any perfect field.

Comment: I haved see Illusie's paper, it is true even in some affine case ($X$ is affine ), but I think it may has obstruction in case of  smooth projective curve.